# Vector calculus and undefined operations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is perhaps a somewhat philosophical question. I'm working with multivariate equations and require the calculation of their Jacobians/Hessians. In order to work it out, I am resorting to representing the equations in their scalar forms to be able to achieve this.

**Example**

For $\vec{y}, \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ we have
\begin{equation} f(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}^T \left( \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\vec{x}^T X}} \right) \end{equation}

In the above, $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\vec{x}^T X}} = \vec{u}$ and $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Now in order to compute the gradient using the vector-matrix notation, I would end up having to expand the derivative so ($\hat{e}_1$, $\hat{e}_2$ are basis vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^2$):

\begin{equation} \nabla f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( y_1 \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-X_{11} x_1 - X_{12} x_2}}\right) + y_2 \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-X_{21} x_1 - X_{22} x_2}}\right) \right) \hat{e}_i \end{equation}

because, if I were to attempt to derive the gradient using the vector notations, I would end up with:
\begin{equation} \nabla f(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}^T \frac{X e^{-\vec{x}^T X}}{(1 + e^{-\vec{x}^T X})^2} \end{equation}

which does not make any sense because there are no operations defined for the squaring of a vector and finding its inverse etc etc.

**Question**: Which convention/formulation would I have to choose to reduce the work involved in calculating the gradient vector of such a function in multivariate/vector calculus?

Comment: Your example looks weird anyways, what is $e^{-x^T X}$ supposed to mean? I see a vector in the exponent, and I don't know how to take the exponent of a vector. Edit: looking at your first expression for the gradient, I think I see what you mean but it's still bad notation.

Comment: It could be bad notation, but I was looking to transcend cumbersome representations to be able reach my solution as quickly and with as little paper consumption as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}((A^TB)^T) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A$$

To avoid confusion with the vector $x$, rename the matrix $X$ to $A$.

Also define the column vectors
$$\eqalign{
p &= -A^Tx
 \quad&\implies\quad &dp = -A^Tdx \\
q &= \exp(p)
 \quad&\implies\quad &dq = q\odot dp \qquad\big({\rm Hadamard\,product}\big) \\
r &= {\tt1}+q
 \quad&\implies\quad &dr = dq \\
s &= \frac{1}{r}
 \quad&\implies\quad &ds = \frac{(-1)dr}{r^{\odot 2}} = -s\odot s\odot dr \\
}$$
Write the function of interest $(\phi)$ in terms of these new vectors,
then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= y:s \\
d\phi &= y:ds \\
 &= -y:(s\odot s\odot dr) \\
 &= -(s\odot s\odot y):dq \\
 &= +(s\odot s\odot y):(q\odot A^Tdx) \\
 &= A(q\odot s\odot s\odot y):dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= A(q\odot s\odot s\odot y) \;=\; g
\qquad\big({\rm the\,gradient}\big) \\
}$$
By forming diagonal matrices from the vectors, e.g.
$$\eqalign{Q = {\rm Diag}(q),\quad R = {\rm Diag}(r),\quad etc.}$$
the Hadamard products can be replaced, and the gradient can be written as
$$\eqalign{
g &= AQS^2 y \;=\; AQ(I+Q)^{-2} y \\
}$$
The Hessian is simply the gradient of the gradient, therefore
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= A\,dQ(I+Q)^{-2}y + AQ\,d(I+Q)^{-2}\,y \\
 &= A(I+Q)^{-2}\,dQ\,y -2AQ(I+Q)^{-3}\,dQ\,y \\
 &= A(I+Q)^{-2}Y\,dq -2AQ(I+Q)^{-3}Y\,dq \\
 &= A\Big((I+Q)-2Q\Big)(I+Q)^{-3}Y\,dq \\
 &= A(I-Q)(I+Q)^{-3}YQ\,dp \\
 &= A(Q-I)(I+Q)^{-3}YQA^Tdx \\
 &= A(Q^2-Q)(I+Q)^{-3}YA^Tdx \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= A(Q^2-Q)(I+Q)^{-3}YA^T \;=\; H
\qquad\big({\rm the\,Hessian}\big) \\
}$$
**NB:**   Some steps take advantage of the fact that diagonal matrices commute, as do their products with vectors, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
Qy &= q\odot y = y\odot q = Yq \\
}$$

Comment: Very elegant answer, this is exactly what i was looking for. I did not know that Frobenius and Hadamard products could be applied to vectors. I suppose it would make sense if I were to look at the vectors as tensors and define the operations on tensors.

Comment: I found this "promotion" of vector to matrix (e.g. by saying $Q = \mathbb{I}\vec{q}$) as preparation for the Hessian calculation very interesting... Maybe you could help me a bit further when the problem gets a little bit more complicated:

if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$,  $\vec{x}, \vec{g} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and, \begin{equation}\vec{g} = (\vec{b} \odot A\vec{x}) : A\end{equation} is the gradient, how could I play around with this to arrive at the Hessian, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Comment: Sorry that I'm not letting off, but I think you could help me out. Now, perhaps this is better put, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\vec{dx}, \vec{g} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have the gradient: \begin{equation} \vec{g} = (\vec{b} \odot A \vec{dx}) : A \end{equation}
Now I need to get $\vec{dx}$ on either side of the Frobenius product so that I can compute the Hessian $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. The way I see it, this cannot be done without converting $\vec{b} \odot A\vec{dx}$ into some matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. How would you do this?

Comment: Let $B={\rm Diag}(b)$, then 
$$\eqalign{
dg &= b\odot A\,dx = BA\,dx \\
\frac{dg}{dx}&= BA \\
}$$
However, the expression $$(b\odot A\,dx):A$$ makes no sense. 
The tensor on each side of a Frobenius (or Hadamard) product 
must be **exactly** the same size. 
For example, the following are valid expressions
$$\eqalign{
g&\,:\,x \\
g&\odot\; x \\
x&\,:\,A^Tb \\
x&\odot\; A^Tb\\
A&\,:\,bx^T \\
(g\odot x)&\,:\,(g\odot x) \\
}$$

Comment: I meant $(\vec{b} \odot A\vec{dx})^T A$. Much appreciated, I feel like you have helped me gain a better understanding of something in tensor calculus!

Comment: So what you really have (making all vectors into column vectors)  is $dg^T=(BA\,dx)^TA$ so $$\eqalign{dg &= A^TBA\,dx\\ \frac{dg}{dx} &= A^TBA\\}$$